# Sorting an Array in C from low to high (without using qsort)

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a functions, which takes an Array of numbers, and sort them from low to high. So far, I have this algorithm, however the output isn't what I'm expecting. Can someone shed some light on it. I cannot use any C library functions.

```
/* 
   Sort "count" numbers stored in array numbers[] in non-decreasing order.
   There may be duplicate numbers in the array.
   You may use any sorting algorithm that you know.
 */

void sort( double numbers[], int count )
{
    int i, j, k;
    //printf("%d", count);

    double temp;
    do{
        j = 0;  
        for (i = 0;i<=count;i++){
                if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]){//this was numbers[k], which was an error
                    j = 1;
                    temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
                    numbers[i+1] = temp;
                }
            }
    } while (j == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition in `for` loop `i<=count` is incorrect.

Valid index in the array are `0` to `count-1`.
Since you are accessing value at index `i+1` in the loop:

```
if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1])
```

`i` can take the value from `0` to `count-2`, so change the condition to    `i<=count-2` or `i<count-1`

Comment: Good to know that..but don't forget to read wiki link give by @stillstanding. Your implementation can be optimized.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to implement the bubble sort algorithm. [Read this to understand what your code is missing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 0):

The value of `k` is used, but the variable is never initialized or assigned to.  At some point your code will try to access the value `numbers[count]`, when an array containing `count` elements has maximum index `count-1`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initalised `k`.

The algorithm will stop as soon as it has moved just one number. You need to move all of them.

I think you are missing a for loop on `k` outside the while loop, but as I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here I can't be sure.

Why can't you implement your own qsort() function? Is that allowed? Try reading up on a few sorting algorithms online.

Answer (score 0):

if (numbers[i] > numbers[k]){

should probably be

if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]){

`k` isn't used at all.

```
for (i = 0;i <= count;i++){
```

should probably be

```
for (i = 0; i < count-1;i++){
```

as there are only elements from 0 to count-1, and then you are comparing to the next one.
The name for `j` is crap. Make it a boolean called didSwap. And then rethink about your codition, maybe it's just the other way around...

Comment: That's why I mentioned the count thing - but SO messed up with the text and didn't show the full code...